# No instance for Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField.FromField Char

Tags: sqlite, haskell

This code gives me an error:

```
67:    isFileInstalled f = do
68:                dbcon <- open "/var/lib/beaver/pkgs.db"
69:                res <- queryNamed dbcon "SELECT * FROM files WHERE path = :path" [":path" := ("/usr/bin/getpkg" :: String)]
70:                mapM_ putStrLn res
71:                -- when (null res) (return ())
72:                -- putStrLn ("File " ++ res ++ " is already installed and comes from " ++ res ++ ".") -- first res is `owner` and second is `path`
73:                close dbcon
74:                exit
```

I get this error:

```
No instance for (Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField.FromField Char)
     arising from a use of `queryNamed'    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
     res <- queryNamed
              dbcon
              "SELECT * FROM files WHERE path = :path"
              [":path" := ("/usr/bin/getpkg" :: String)]    In the expression:
     do { dbcon <- open "/var/lib/beaver/pkgs.db";
          res <- queryNamed
                   dbcon
                   "SELECT * FROM files WHERE path = :path"
                   [":path" := ("/usr/bin/getpkg" :: String)];
          mapM_ putStrLn res;
          close dbcon;
          .... }    In an equation for `isFileInstalled':
       isFileInstalled f
         = do { dbcon <- open "/var/lib/beaver/pkgs.db";
                res <- queryNamed
                         dbcon
                         "SELECT * FROM files WHERE path = :path"
                         [":path" := ("/usr/bin/getpkg" :: String)];
                mapM_ putStrLn res;
```

I didn't find anything in Google. If it's important, OverloadedStrings are enabled. Is there workaround (or way to fix it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `res` as a `[String]`:

```
mapM_ putStrLn res
```

It is equivalent to `[[Char]]`. But `queryNamed` returns a list of rows, so each row has type `[Char]`. There is an `instance FromField a => FromRow [a]`, but there is no `instance FromField Char`. That is what the error messages says.

I never used `sqlite-simple`, but it is clear that each row contains a number of fields, so you are trying to fetch a row that contains a number of fields of type `Char`. That makes no sense. Depending on actual database scheme, each row should be e.g. a number of text field, then the `res` can have type `[[String]]`. In that case you should use it like the next:

```
mapM_ (mapM_ putStrLn) (res :: [[String]])
```

Comment: Will be this same if request will be limited to one row?

Comment: @Piesek64 yes, the compiler can't know at compile time how many rows the query may return

Comment: Applied the patch from your message and new problem. http://pastebin.com/vtEMY60C

Comment: @Piesek64 add an explicit type signature for `res`. `mapM_` is not limited to lists in `ghc-7.10`, so the compiler needs a hint.

Comment: Sorry if I am irritating but I am new to Haskell. How can I do that?